# Browse a numeric data array and add or subtract during the loop with $.each

Tags: jquery

It may be that this question has already been posted, but I have not found any clear solution to my problem.

The title of my question has already described my problem. In fact I wish to see the sum of the sum during the loop. But when you meet a negative number, it turns into a positive number. Which distorts the result.
Below an example of my loop.

Can you help me please ?

```
<table>
  <tr id="testTable">
     <td data-pos="0"></td>
     <td data-pos="1"></td>
     <td data-pos="2"></td>
     <td data-pos="3"></td>
     <td data-pos="4"></td>
     <td data-pos="5"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var array = [200, 400, 200, -500, 200,100];

        var sum = 0;
        $.each(array, function (i, val) {
            val = parseFloat(val);
            if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
                if (val > 0) {
                    sum += val;
                } else {
                    sum -= val;
                }
            }
            $('tr#testTable td[data-pos="'+i+'"]').text(sum);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result is **1600** instead of **600**

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Do you really need to use `$.each()`? Why not `Array.reduce`?

Comment: Why you do not want to use reduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use `.reduce()`. Coming to your question, the problem is in the `if` condition. Let's say the value is `-500`.

```
if (val > 0) {
    sum += val;
} else {
    // val is -500 and it comes here.
    // sum will be set to sum - (-500)
    // the above will be sum + 500
    sum -= val;
}
```

Your logic here is flawed.

You just need to use:

```
if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
  sum += val;
}
```

**Snippet**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="testTable">
    <td data-pos="0"></td>
    <td data-pos="1"></td>
    <td data-pos="2"></td>
    <td data-pos="3"></td>
    <td data-pos="4"></td>
    <td data-pos="5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var array = [200, 400, 200, -500, 200, 100];

    var sum = 0;
    $.each(array, function(i, val) {
      val = parseFloat(val);
      if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
        sum += val;
      }
      $('tr#testTable td[data-pos="' + i + '"]').text(sum);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I am indeed getting **600** as the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sources from the if condition that you are using. You don't need to check whether the value is negative or positive, but just to add it in the sum. 
When you check if the value is negative, in reality it reverses the sign of the number, which means that a negative number becomes positive.
I would recommend the use of .reduce, rather the unnecessary declaration of variables. However, the solution with `$.each` would be:

**$.each(callback)**

```
let array = [200, 400, 200, -500, 200, 100];
let s = 0;
$.each(array, (i,v)=> s + v);
```

A simpler solution with vanillaJS is:

```
let sum = [200, 400, 200, -500, 200,100].reduce((s,v) => s + v ,0)
```

Comment: The question specifically says they want to use `$.each()`